# How to best typeset this long matrix multiplication?

Tags: align, matrices

I have a quite large matrix multiplication:

```
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)&\approx \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*}) &\frac{\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}}&-\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*}) &\mathrm{Cov}(\zeta^{*},\pi) & \mathrm{Cov}(\zeta^{*},\delta^{*}) \\\mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) & \mathrm{Var}(\pi) & \mathrm{Cov}(\pi, \delta^{*}) \\\mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) & \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi) & \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*}) \\\frac{\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}}\\-\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\end{pmatrix}
        \end{align*}
```

Since this does not fit a single line I am wondering how I could typeset this in the best way? So that the logic of the matrix multiplication is still visible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments. It is shorter and clearer if you highlight the fact that this is VAV^T:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)&\approx 
V\begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*}) &\mathrm{Cov}(\zeta^{*},\pi) & \mathrm{Cov}(\zeta^{*},\delta^{*}) \\\mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) & \mathrm{Var}(\pi) & \mathrm{Cov}(\pi, \delta^{*}) \\\mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) & \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi) & \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) \end{pmatrix}V^T
        \end{align*}
where
\[V=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*}) &\frac{\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}}&-\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\end{pmatrix} \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably a `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` is better looking here?

Comment: Using `\DeclareMathOperator` for “Var” and “Cov” should be recommended

Answer (score 5):

Like David Carlisle does in his answer, I would also reduce the overall visual complexity of the main equation by rewriting it in the form `V(a)=V <some matrix> V^T` and providing a separate equation to explain the structure of `V^T`. Furthermore, in order to enhance the appearance of the components of the 3x3 matrix and the 3x1 column vector I would suggest that you do *not* use the `pmatrix` environment, which centers the contents of each column. Instead, it may be better to use the more general `array` environment to left-align the columns in the matrix and to right-align the column vector. Additionally, the legibility of the code (and look of the output) are enhanced, I think, if one defines the math operator terms `\Var` and `\Cov` in the preamble and then uses them throughout the equations.

[image]

If you feel so inclined, you can simplify the expression for `V^T` further by factoring out the common term `\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Var(\alpha) &\approx V
\left( \begin{array}{lll} 
\Var(\zeta^{*})            &\Cov(\zeta^{*},\pi)   & \Cov(\zeta^{*},\delta^{*}) \\
\Cov(\pi,\zeta^{*})        & \Var(\pi)            & \Cov(\pi, \delta^{*}) \\
\Cov(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) & \Cov(\delta^{*},\pi) & \Var(\delta^{*}) 
\end{array} \right)
V^T\\
\intertext{where}
V^T &= 
\left( \begin{array}{@{}r}
\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\,\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*}) \\
\pi/(\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}})\, \exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
-\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\,\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```